# save list of images to files with magick

Tags: r, purrr

I am trying to understand purrr, and how to map/walk over a list of images and save them to files.  Below is my code that works using a for loop, but how would this be structured using purrr?  I am confused by the various versions (walk, walk2, pwalk, map, map2, pmap etc.)

```
library(magick)
library(purrr)

#create a list of the files
inpath <- "C:\\Path\\To\\Images"

file_list <- list.files(path = inpath, full.names = TRUE)

# read the files and negate them
imgn <- map(file_list, image_read) %>% 
  map(image_negate)

# assign list names as original file names
names(imgn) = list.files(path = inpath)

# how to use walk, map, map2?  walk2, pwalk? to do this
for (i in 1:length(imgn)) {
  
  image_write(imgn[[i]], path = names(imgn)[[i]])

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm correct in understanding your code, it looks like you're trying to save your edited images to their original file paths. If so, could you replace your for loop with:

```
map2(imgn, file_list, ~ image_write(.x, path = .y))
```

As an explanation, you want to use `map2` because you're applying a function with two inputs; the image you're saving (stored in `imgn`), and the filepath you're writing it to (stored in `file_list`). You can then use formula notation to specify the function and arguments you'd like to map, as above (more on this in the `map` docs).

Answer (score 2):

Using `Map` from `base R`

```
Map(function(x, y) image_write(x, path = y), imgn, file_list)
```